# Thread not moving to notify after wait is being called

Tags: android, multithreading

I have this below piece of code, I want to my thread to wait untill either of the callback functions are called.

Issue my code hits the line where i am making the `synchObj` wait but after that it just vanishes it doesn't move anywhere.

If after wait its not gonna move ahead how the `notify` will be called?

```
iGPlaceApi.getStreams(new Callback<mGooglePlacesApiResponse>() {

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        String serverResponse = retrofitError.toString();
        synchronized (synchObj) {
            synchObj.notify();
            //synchObj.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void success(mGooglePlacesApiResponse googlePlacesObj, Response arg1){
        nearbyPlaces = new String[googlePlacesObj.results.size()][4];
        for (int i = 0; i < googlePlacesObj.results.size(); i++) {
            mGooglePlaces.place place = googlePlacesObj.results.get(i);
            nearbyPlaces[i][0] = place.icon;
            nearbyPlaces[i][1] = place.name;
            nearbyPlaces[i][2] = String.valueOf(place.geometry.location.lat);
            nearbyPlaces[i][3] = String.valueOf(place.geometry.location.lng);
        }
        synchronized (synchObj) {
            synchObj.notify();
            //synchObj.notifyAll();
        }
    }

});

synchronized (synchObj) {
    synchObj.wait();
}
```

---

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
            Runnable thr = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    iGPlaceApi.getStreams(new Callback<mGooglePlacesApiResponse>() {

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                            String serverResponse = retrofitError.toString();
                            synchronized (synchObj) {
                                synchObj.notifyAll();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void success(mGooglePlacesApiResponse googlePlacesObj, Response arg1) {
                            nearbyPlaces = new String[googlePlacesObj.results.size()][4];
                            for (int i = 0; i < googlePlacesObj.results.size(); i++) {
                                mGooglePlaces.place place = googlePlacesObj.results.get(i);
                                nearbyPlaces[i][0] = place.icon;
                                nearbyPlaces[i][1] = place.name;
                                nearbyPlaces[i][2] = String.valueOf(place.geometry.location.lat);
                                nearbyPlaces[i][3] = String.valueOf(place.geometry.location.lng);
                            }
                            synchronized (synchObj) {
                                synchObj.notifyAll();
                            }

                        }

                    });
                }
            };
            handler.post(thr);

            synchronized (synchObj) {
                synchObj.wait();
            }
```

Comment: are you making wait the UI Thread?

Comment: No, its a different thread.

Comment: ok then :). The snippet looks good (I had used notifyAll instead of notify). You should probably post a little bit more of code, and try to rephrase the description a little bit (I am not sure what's the problem)

Comment: So unless there is a more sinister problem i would debug it by just ensuring that my callback is ever getting called ( so i would remove wait and check.. if that's happening then I would check if the thread you are stopping ( using wait ) is it responsible for calling callback? ..

Comment: @UncleKing Callbacks are working without wait/notify.

`blackbelt:` What i want to achieve is, i want this above function not to return until either one of callback functions are called i.e. a failure or a success. Because my next lines of code depends over the value returned.

Comment: but then can't you just move the line on a method and call the method when success is called?

Comment: Did you verify my second part of the comment ? is getStreams async?

Comment: @UncleKing how can i ensure that, the function is from `RetroFit` library

Comment: And even if it is on a different thread, shouldnt `notifyAll()` work in that case. Because its not, also tried that.

Comment: Well.. haven't worked with RetroFit library to know - but think of this.. your thread who's going to call the notifyAll is probably the same thread which is in "wait"

Comment: So you mean to say these two threads should be different? Means i need to create a new thread and call `getStreams` and `notify` in that while `wait` is in other thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. The callbacks are going to be called on the same thread that is calling the `getStreams` method.

The callbacks cannot be called until your calling method returns. You probably need to call `getStreams` in yet another thread.

Comment: So you mean to say these two threads should be different? Means i need to create a new thread and call `getStreams` and `synchObj.notify` in that new thread while `synchObj.wait();` is in other thread? They both CANT be in same thread?

Comment: that is what i mean, yes. You cannot call notify and wait on the same thread, since wait put the thread in pause, meaning it is not executing any more code, meaning it cannot execute `notify`.

Comment: please check my updated code, have moved `notifyAll` into seperate thread but still no benefit. Also tried with `new Thread()` but same.

Comment: handler.post posts on the thread on which was created the handler (or on the ui thread, not entirely sure) anyway, your post can never be executed. Why don't you use a listener mechanism rather than trying to force your method to be synchronous?

Comment: give me a hint what to use to implement above plz.
I have already spent much time in trying ti implement wait-notify. going towards using another new mechanism would be like starting for zero.

Comment: i don't get it. why are you trying to force the method to by synchronous if you explicitly declared it to be asynchronous in the first place?

Comment: `getStreams` is not my function its a part of `RetroFit` library, which has it as `asynchronous`

Comment: @Maven: isn't that supposed to be from an interface that you defined?

Comment: @Maven: see section `SYNCHRONOUS VS. ASYNCHRONOUS` in http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. Handler task will be executed on the same thread so in your case it will never be executed. If you want to wait for your task to be done you should use Thread like this:

```
// defined somewhere
boolean done = false;
Thread thr=new Thread(Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        iGPlaceApi.getStreams(new Callback<mGooglePlacesApiResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                String serverResponse = retrofitError.toString();
                        synchronized (synchObj) {
                            done = true;
                            synchObj.notifyAll();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void success(mGooglePlacesApiResponse googlePlacesObj, Response arg1) {
                        nearbyPlaces = new String[googlePlacesObj.results.size()][4];
                        for (int i = 0; i < googlePlacesObj.results.size(); i++) {
                            mGooglePlaces.place place = googlePlacesObj.results.get(i);
                            nearbyPlaces[i][0] = place.icon;
                            nearbyPlaces[i][1] = place.name;
                            nearbyPlaces[i][2] = String.valueOf(place.geometry.location.lat);
                            nearbyPlaces[i][3] = String.valueOf(place.geometry.location.lng);
                        }
                        synchronized (synchObj) {
                            done = true;
                            synchObj.notifyAll();
                        }

                    }

                });
            }
        });
        thr.start();

        synchronized (synchObj) {
            while (!done) {
                synchObj.wait();
            }
        }
```

Note that instead of just runnable I'm using Thread, and done variable which indicates task status which is neccesary since wait call can spontaneously wake up and you have to call it again if the task has not been finished yet.